# How to do forgot password in keycloak via API

Tags: oauth, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

We are creating an app that has a feature to reset their password respectively, since we are using keycloak so that thing will be featured via keycloak page itself, but our client need the forgot password will be provided in the app, so i need to hit the forgot password api like below flow.

App Forgot Password Page > Fill email only and proceed > User receive reset password link > Open link > Keycloak reset password page

But seems that api is not existed in the keycloak.

As far i only found below apis

- `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password`  (need bearer, not possible since we are unable to use realm account user)
- `PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/execute-actions-email`  (don't know how to use it and need bearer, not possible since we are unable to use realm account user)

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance

---

Hi there, this is 2021, my solution at this time was by using keycloak library in java service, so the service working as aggregator between my web app to keycloak, and still we are using above apis mentioned that need realm access. Good luck.

Comment: please provide your detailed solution as an answer, and mark it as the correct answer. This way, we can all learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can set required action for the user to `UPDATE_PASSWORD` and when user tries to log in, they will be prompted with Setting up their password.

[Keycloak Admin APIs - UserResource](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource)
You can update the user and in the `UserRepresentation` you can set that required action.

Comment: Obviously, it doesn't answer the question as a user who has forgotten his password can't login.

Comment: I think this API is not for forgetting passwords, this is for updating the action, and this API will be triggered by the admin.
If anyone knows the API for forgetting passwords, kindly let me know.